# buildtime vs runtime - how do i share variables/code from Package.js with the package code itself?

Tags: meteor, package

I have a package that needs to define a bunch of asset files (at build time), for the package, the tests, and within the package itself (at run time).

Is there a way to share these variables? eg:

```
// package.js

// var shared across test and package def
var BrainFiles = [
    "data/begin.rive",
    "data/start.rive",
    "data/nav.rive"
  ]

Package.on_use(function(api) {
  api.addFiles(BrainFiles, ['server'], 
    {isAsset: true} 
  )

  ...
}

Package.on_test(function (api) {
  api.addFiles(BrainFiles, ['server'], 
    {isAsset: true} 
  )
  ...
}

// then within the package code i want to refer to Brainfiles
```

I guess the other approach would be to write a folder scanning function, but that code would also have to be shared between package.js and the package code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but I would create an `Asset` file `brain-files.json`

```
//brain-files.json
[
  "data/begin.rive",
  "data/start.rive",
  "data/nav.rive"
]
```

Read/parse it in your `package.js` with [`fs`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options)

```
//package.js
Package.on_use(function(api) {
  var fs = Npm.require('fs')
  var BrainFiles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('brain-files.json'));
  api.addFiles(BrainFiles, 'server', {isAsset: true});

  // sets a `BrainFiles` variable for other files that are included
  api.addFiles('brain-files.json', 'server', {isAsset: true});
  api.addFiles('read-brain-files.js', 'server');

  ...
}
```

And read/parse in a js file `read-brain-files.js` with [`Assets.getText()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/assets_getText)

```
//read-brain-files.js
// no var, this should be accessible by all files in your package
BrainFiles = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('/packages/my-package/brain-files.json'));
```

Comment: are you saying that brain-files.json would be a list of files? I'm not sure your code above would read in the list, then iterate through, but i think I get the idea. I don't know if you can Assets.getText inside the Package.js though. You would have to do that in both places for this approach to make sense.

Comment: Hi @dcsan, I've updated my answer to clarify. You use `fs.readFileSync` in `package.js` to read the `.json`; and you use `Assets.getText` to read it in the package code.